# Run CTS only for 64bit target and not for 32bit target

Tags: android, camera, cts

I run camera Android 7 CTS for 64bit target with below mentioned command but all CTS run twice first for 64 bit target and next for 32 bit.

```
run cts-camera --skip-precondition
```

Is there any option which can be mentioned in command while running CTS so that it will run only for one 64bit case.

Answer (score 1):

We have option in cts tradefed to run only on perticular abi mode either 64 bit or 32 bit

--abi  : Force the test to run on the given ABI, 32 or 64. By default CTS runs a test once for each ABI the device supports.

run cts -m  -t  -a

armeabi-v7a  : 32 bit
arm64-v8a : 64 bit

Comment: Somthing like run "run cts-camera --abi arm64-v8a --skip-preconditions" or "run cts-camera --abi armeabi-v7a --skip-preconditions"?